# JavaScript function gets 100x slower for no obvious reason

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function drawRect(rect, color, filled) {
    const width = this.width;
    const x = rect.x;
    const y = rect.y;
    const w = rect.w;
    const h = rect.h;

    console.time('drawRect');
    for (let _y = y; _y < y + h; _y++) {
      for (let _x = x; _x < x + w; _x++) {
         this.data[(_x + this.width * _y) * 4 + 0] = color.red;
         this.data[(_x + this.width * _y) * 4 + 1] = color.green;
         this.data[(_x + this.width * _y) * 4 + 2] = color.blue;
         this.data[(_x + this.width * _y) * 4 + 3] = color.alpha * 255;
      }
    }
    console.timeEnd('drawRect');
}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is write my own Canvas-like wrapper around a big ImageData blob. (That's what `this.data` is.)

I wrote this function in a self-contained environment and tested it. It ran very quickly (less than 1ms generally).

I then copied it over to the app that I intended to use it in. **Suddenly, although the function continues to work, it runs at least 100x slower.** The output from `console.time` has gone from ~1ms to over 100ms.

I have tested it with the exact same arguments in both the small app and the large app. The exact same invocation of this function runs 100x slower in the larger app.

I looked in the Chrome profiling tools, and the function does not show an icon saying that it is unoptimized.

**What could possibly cause a function to run 100x slower when put in a larger codebase?**

I'm sorry, but I cannot provide a MCVE. I simply cannot narrow down my huge app to see which part of it is causing the slowdown. In fact, that's exactly what I'd like to know, because I have no clue where to even begin looking.

Comment: Did you look into optimization killers for V8? https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers

Comment: can you even show the `self-contained environment` perhaps?

Comment: `this` belong to something else in your loop and you can set your constant on current object like `const this.x = rect.x;` and so on.

Comment: or ... perhaps an indication of the dimensions of `rect`

Comment: In the cases that I'm testing, rect is `{ x: 0, y: 0, w: 500, h: 500 }`

Comment: I could make the above example a bit more self contained if that would help, sure.

Comment: @thedayturns then where does width come from `const width = this.width;`

Comment: @MaciejJankowski yes, I did look through that. it seems like most of what it lists is specific to the deoptimized function, right? And my function seems pretty simple, definitely doesn't contain e.g. forin, debugger, stuff like that...

Comment: @Jai My bad, yeah, the function is part of a larger class. Is it possible that the class could somehow deoptimize the function? `width` is just a property on the class, as is `data`

Comment: would setting `h = rect.h + y` then the test in the for  `_y <  h` - similarly for w and x - make any improvement? not an answer to your problem, just an observation about the code in general

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, that improvement would probably be on the order or 5% or so.

Comment: preincrement  `++_y` is apparently faster than postincrement too (sorry, I'm not really helping the actual issue) ... `+=1` even faster (again, tiny improvements)

Comment: yeah, those are mostly microoptimizations, which i'm not opposed to, but i'd prefer to hear about ...err... macrooptimizations? :P

Comment: yeah, I know ... it's hard to tell what could be the issue ... is `data` the data property of a `ImageData` object by the way?

Comment: `data` is a Uint32Array view onto an ArrayBuffer. And yeah I know that it's hard to know what the issue was. I was kind of expecting this question just to be closed because it's so obscure.

Comment: Curiously, the invocation of the function is very snappy before I initialize the app, but much slower after the app initializes.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I figured it out. Maybe this will help someone in the future with the same issue, who knows.

It turned out that **I was accessing the Uint8Array (`this.data`) at a negative index**, due to a coding error. It was this access that caused Chrome's profiler to catastrophically explode.

A *single* negative access will cause the function to be deoptimized *forever.*

If you run into optimization issues with Canvas stuff, make sure you're not indexing out of bounds!